# CSS height when using background-size

Tags: css, mobile

So I wanted to resize the background image of a `div` using `background-size: contain`, and I set the `width` to 100%. I need this for a mobile site, where the dimension of the screen is variable. However, i have a dilemma when setting the height.

If I set the height in pixels, when the picture becomes smaller, it leaves an empty space below the picture.

If I don't set the height, the picture won't appear at all.

What's the best solution to this?

Here's my code:

```
<div id="container">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <div id="my-picture"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
}
#my-picture {
    background:url(somepic.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    height: ???
}
```

Comment: It depends on how large you want the element to be. Of course there will be empty space below an element if the viewport is taller than needed for the content. The issue seems to be about overall page layout rather than about background sizing.

Answer (score 1):

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) you should use *Background-size: cover;*

```
#my-picture {
  background:url(somepic.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: ???
}
```

Comment: The question clearly says that `background-size: contain` is what is wanted. See also http://w3fools.com